# Не работает realloc

Tags: c

Написал код для удаления главной диагонали:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <locale.h> 

void swap(int *a, int *b) 
{ 
int temp = *a; 
*a = *b; 
*b = temp; 
} 

void matrix(int n,int **p,int **ab) 
{ 

int i, j,a,b; 

//srand(time(NULL)); 
printf("\nВведите пределы чисел массива:\n"); 
scanf_s("%d %d", &a, &b); 
printf("\n Обычная:\n"); 
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{ 
for (j = 0; j < n; j++) 
{ 
*(p + i * n + j) = a+ rand() % (b-a+1); 
printf("%3d ", *(p + i * n + j)); 
} 
printf("\n"); 
} 



printf("\n\n Cиметрия относительно побочной диагонали:\n"); 
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{ 
for (j = 0; j < n; j++) 
{ 
if ((i + j) < (n - 1)) 
{ 
swap((p + i * n + j), (p + (n - j - 1)*n + (n - i - 1))); 
} 
printf("%3d ", *(p + i * n + j)); 

} 
printf("\n"); 
} 
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{ 
for (j = 0; j < n; j++) 
{ 
if (i == j) 
{ 
for (a = i; a < n - 1; a++) 
{ 
*(p + a * n + j) = *(p + (a + 1) * n + j); 
} 

} 
} 
} 
p = (int*)realloc(p,n*(n-1) * sizeof(int)); 

if (n == 1) 
{ 
printf_s("\n\n Матрица удалена полностью"); 
}  
else 
{ 
printf_s("\n\n Матрица с удаленной главной диагональю:\n"); 
for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
{ 
for (j = 0; j < n; j++) 
{ 

printf("%3d ", *(p + i * n + j)); 

} 
printf("\n"); 
} 
}  

} 

int main() 
{ 
setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS"); 
int **p, n, i, j,**ab; 
printf_s("введите n\n"); 
scanf_s("%d", &n); 
p = (int*)malloc(n*n * sizeof(int)); 

matrix(n,&p,&ab); 

_getch(); 
free(p); 
return 0; 
}
```

И компилятор ругается на `p = (int*)realloc(p,n*(n-1) * sizeof(int));`
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А что он пишет?

Comment: Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x77610A98 (ntdll.dll) в 9lab.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000014

Comment: У вас большая проблема в непонимании типов. Не в `realloc` дело. `p` объявлен как `int**`, а вы его все время пытаетесь использовать как `int*`... Отсюда все неприятности - в том числе из-за неверного использования `p` - слет программы. Вы что, совсем не смотрите на предупреждения компилятора? Впрочем, ошибки и в самом методе решения также имеются. Это мягко говоря...

Comment: Во-первых, ошибка "Вызвано исключение по адресу..." никакого отношения к компилятору не имеет. Во-вторых компилятор ясно указал вам на ошибку уже в `p = (int*)malloc(n*n * sizeof(int));`. (И здесь вам уже на эту бессмыслицу уже указывали в ваших предыдущих вопросах). Вы просто проигнорировали диагностические сообщения компилятора?

Comment: @Alex первый раз вижу, чтобы так ругался компилятор :)) Это, вообще-то, ошибка времени выполнения :)